# Validating Wordpress user externally via JSON API

Tags: wordpress

I have an external REST service that processes and validates form data from various sites.

One of the things I need to be able to do is somehow query wordpress from this service to see if a user is valid. This can be via an email address, but even better as some kind of member-number.

I've seen some documentation on the current WP JSON API, and it appears that it's only possible to get data for users that have published an article.

I would love it if wordpress had the ability to generate a member-id (not the same as the uid) that I could use to query for users externally.

So my question is: Is there a plugin I can use that will allow me to query for valid WP users via webservice? and secondly is there an easy way to generate a member id for each new user and store that somewhere that can also be queried by the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work-around this as I am also using paid memberships pro (plugin). They have example code that can be put in functions.php that will expose the $user and membership objects. The link is here: [PMPro JSON API Howto](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/interacting-with-paid-memberships-pro-through-apis/)
It's also possible to expose this if you use Woocommerce which has a pretty awesome JSON API.